# using puppeteer with headless_shell

Tags: pdf-generation, puppeteer

I am using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-pdf which has puppeteer as a dependency.

Heroku is angry about my >500mb slug size, so I am trying to reduce it.

It looks like if I can setup puppeteer to use headless_shell instead of the full chromium download, then I can greatly reduce size of my npm modules.

However I am struggling to get it installed and working with headless_shell:

```
mkdir headless && cd headless
npm init -y
touch .npmrc
echo "PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true" > .npmrc
npm i puppeteer
```

Then I run `node` and try to launch puppeteer:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
puppeteer.launch({executablePath: 'out/Release/headless_shell'});

Uncaught:
Error: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn out/Release/headless_shell ENOENT


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (/Users/me/delete/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:194:20)
```

If anyone knows how to get setup with headless_shell that would be great.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? I also have issues on Heroku with the puppeteer size.

Comment: No, unfortunately this is still a problem for us.