# How to reduce Puppeteer size

Tags: node.js, heroku, puppeteer, node-modules, chromium

I'm using Puppeteer for webscraping, with a small NodeJs webapp that I made. This webapp is hosted on Heroku and use `jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack` to works.

The problem I'm facing is that my app do not build anymore because of the Heroku size limit:

```
Compiled slug size: 537.4M is too large (max is 500M).
```

I've tried severals things:

- Using Firefox instead of Chromium

  - It's a "no go" for me because of a [current issue with puppeteer/firefox](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6359):
- Reducing the size of Chromium by [removing the file `interactive_ui_tests.exe`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/842)

  - I can't do this because Heroku use Linux instead of Windows, and this file does not exist in the Linux Chromium distribution
- Using `headless_shell` instead of Chromium

  - I'm stuck with this (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68639229/using-puppeteer-with-headless-shell)) as I do not understand how to make it works. I found the file to use [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3140), but I'm facing the same issue as the comment from the 07/09/2018
- Using Playwright instead of Puppeteer

  - It might be a solution, but I'm using stuffs like `puppeteer-extra` and `puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth`, so it bother me to change
- Reducing the size of Chromium by removing the folder `locales`

  - It helps a bit, but not much
- Using an older version of Puppeteer (`2.1.1`), which is using an older version Chromium who was slighlty lighter

  - At the moment, it's the only working solution that I have
- Use the command `heroku repo:gc -a myapp` and `heroku builds:cache:purge -a myapp`

My last three points reduced the size of my slug to `490M`. So my app is working, but it's not great for the (close) future, like having an up to date Puppeteer version.

So here I am, asking for help, as I do not have any more ideas at the moment.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Try https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome or similar package to grab the chromium binary from that one. It's generally much smaller. I know it says "Lambda" but it should work in most Linux distros

Comment: Thanks for your idea! But finally, I end up using Playwright

Comment: as of Dec 2022, added a [non-Playwright answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74858297/8919391) on a similar question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I end up using Playwright.

With [this Buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/playwright-community/heroku-playwright-buildpack), the build of my app is only 250Mb!

Here's a few steps I've followed:

- Install with NPM `playwright-chromium` to only download Chromium.
- Set `PLAYWRIGHT_BUILDPACK_BROWSERS` env variable to `chromium` in Heroku to only install Chromium dependencies.
- Put this buildpack before Node.js buildpack in Heroku.
- With [this trick](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/issues/454#issuecomment-917437212) you can use most of the of stuff from `puppeteer-stealth`.
- If you want, you can block resources like in Puppeteer:

```js
await page.route('**/*', route => ([
    'stylesheet',
    'image',
    'media',
    'font',
    // 'script',
    'texttrack',
    'xhr',
    'fetch',
    'eventsource',
    'websocket',
    'manifest',
    'other',
].includes(route.request().resourceType()) ? route.abort() : route.continue()))
```