# heroku Error: compiled slug size: is too large with Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, heroku, puppeteer, heroku-cli, heroku-api

My app is working on localhost but when i deploy on heroku this module is required for puppeteer app https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack. puppeteer node_module size is around 300mb and this module size is 200.Total size is 539mb. Please suggest a good solution

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution to this problem? I'm also facing it; couldn't resolve yet.

Comment: @Haseeb nope. I deployed the app on Google app engine

Comment: cool thank you, anyway I found the solution to use the Playwright instead. It reduces the bundle size greatly. Here is the guide (if anyone is looking for solution): https://stackoverflow.com/a/69481396/12824406

Answer (score 8):

Faced the same issue.

The following steps reduced my slug size from around 530MB to around 250MB.

---

**1 — Update buildpacks**

Add the `heroku/google-chrome` buildpack. Place it above the `heroku/nodejs` buildpack. The `jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack` is not required here anymore.

[image: buildpacks]

---

**2 — Add new ENV variables**

Add *PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH*. In your local environment, set this env variable as [`\path\to\chrome.exe`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46755247/8919391). In Heroku, set this env variable as `google-chrome`.

Also add *PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD*, and set it to `true`. This tells Puppeteer to skip downloading Chromium.

[image: env variables]

---

**3 — Update Puppeteer config**

Puppeteer's [launch options](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.puppeteerlaunchoptions) includes `executablePath`. Set this to *PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH*.

[image: puppeteer config]

---

**4 — Deploy, you're done!**

Push commit to Heroku to trigger new deployment. Hopefully, your slug size will have reduced by then, and your Heroku app should be able to deploy successfully.

[image: slug size]

Comment: This was very helpful for me! My project's slug size went from ~490mb down to ~290mb. Thank you!

Comment: Seriously! Went from 499.2 to 286. I was also stuck on Puppeteer 18. Thank you so much!